# How to turn off server signature + heroku + ruby on rails

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have one page site and deployed on Heroku. 
While checking SEO, I found that Server Signature is On.

So how can I turn this off?

Comment: What do you mean by that? the CSRF rails has?

Comment: Did my answer work for you Dipak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these two methods to turn off your server signature. In `.htaccess` you can use:

```
ServerSignature Off
```

Just place it at the top of your file. Alternatively you can turn it off by editing your `httpd.conf` file.

Use the following:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

Simple as that.